# Запрос к MySQL с помощью JavaScript без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Всем привет.

Эта таблица выводится в цикле

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>текст 1</td>
        <td><iframe src="quare_05.php?id=1" class="if1"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>текст 2</td>
        <td><iframe src="quare_05.php?id=2" class="if1"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>текст 3</td>
        <td><iframe src="quare_05.php?id=3" class="if1"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>текст 4</td>
        <td><iframe src="quare_05.php?id=4" class="if1"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Есть страничка, в которой внутри таблицы, внутри ячеек, нагружены iframe. iframe определяет id и делает запрос в mysql через страницу re.php, которая изменяет нужную ячейку со значением 0 на 1 или 1 на 0, затем обратно прыгает на quare_05.php выводит кнопку да/нет. Смысл в том, что без JS могу делать запросы к БД, при этом не перезагружая страницу

```
// вычисляем id
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT id,st FROM table ORDER BY id",$db);
while($massiv = mysql_fetch_array($zapros))
{
    if($massiv["st"]==1)
    {
        echo "<form action=\"re.php\" method=\"post\">
              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"field0\" value=\"".$id."\">
              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"field1\" value=\"0\">
              <input type=\"submit\" value=\"да\" class=\"blue\">
              </form>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<form action=\"re.php\" method=\"post\">
              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"field0\" value=\"".$id."\">
              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"field1\" value=\"1\">
              <input type=\"submit\" value=\"нет\" class=\"oran\">
              </form>";
    }
}
```

Можно ли реализовать описанное выше без iframe, а с помощью JS ?

Comment: Да, можно - с помощью AJAX

Comment: здорово. в таком случае, с кодом подскажите?

Comment: Сожалею, но нет. Но в интернете можно найти массу примеров.

Comment: >здорово. в таком случае, с кодом подскажите?

Это работа за автора! Карается закрытием вопроса и/или его удалением.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Подключите библиотеку [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Потом пропишите такой вот код:

```
function load() { //просто какая-нибудь функция 
    $.ajax({
        url: "re.php",
        // файл, к которому обращается скрипт 
        success: function (data) {
            $('.kakoyto_block').html(data);
        } //Здесь в блок с классом (или может быть ид) вставляется то, что ответил сервер, то есть получается загрузка контента без перезагрузки. 
    })
}
```

Смыл думаю понятен, просто переделайте код под себя и будет вам счастье, это конечно говнокод, но я попытался донести смысл и принцип.

Comment: Спасибо большое за этот ответ. Благодаря ему начал понимать jquery.

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли реализовать описанное выше
> без iframe, а с помощью JS ?

Да, можно.